# How to change elements in a list?

Tags: go

If I use `container/list` as

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    x int
}

func main() {
    l := list.New()
    l.PushBack(Data{2})
    a := l.Back()
    v := a.Value.(Data)
    v.x = 1
    
    fmt.Println(l.Back().Value)  // --> {2}
}
```

Well, the value of `x` in the list does not change. What is the correct programming pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments and return values are passed by value in Go. Therefore `v` is a copy of the original `Data` value. Changing it does not affect the one that is stored in the list.

You can get the behaviour you want by inserting a pointer to a `Data` value instead:

```
l := list.New()
l.PushBack(&Data{2})
a := l.Back()
v := a.Value.(*Data)
v.x = 1

fmt.Println(l.Back().Value)  // --> &{1}
```

Comment: @user3431635 please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers